# Emit a single value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I would like to emit a single value.

According to this [post](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754), the following should be valid:

```
var requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');
```

However, this does not work. `just` is not defined.

Has it been deprecated? Is there something that I can use instead?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A lot of the stuff is tucked away in:  `import 'rxjs/Rx';` You might try `Observable.of` for a single value.

This works for me ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j7kVjTaTaLOmDoLB8EdN?p=preview)):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{test | async}}</h2>     
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
    test: Observable<any> = Observable.of("I'm an observable");
    constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: You can import just `of` with `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` instead of `import 'rxjs/Rx'`

Comment: Now it is just a global function `of("value")`

Comment: To avoid side effects i recommend to import of like this: `import {of} from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 28):

`.just(value)` is from RxJS v4 while angular2 is using the v5. It has gone through an extensive rewrite, and it is still in beta so operators are missing/changed names in v5.

`.of` is just fine, as MarkM mentioned. I just wanted to add that you can also use `.from` which works if you have just one value, or an array of values. To reuse the example from your accepted answer, you would use something like ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IdSkxCrIKB9YqJYrC69H?p=preview)):

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{test | async}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
    test: Observable<any> = Observable.from(["I'm an observable"]);
    constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: for array of objects 'from' is throwing error:
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
and 'of' works fine

Answer (score 6):

Use the [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) function:

```js
import {of} from 'rxjs';

var requestStream = of('https://api.github.com/users');
```